# Why MYSQL return 0 for compare string with Boolean?

Tags: mysql

In PHP when I check a string like "Hello" with True/False if string not empty or not equal to zero PHP return True Boolean type , but in MYSQL when I check a string with IS comparison operator , MYSQL return zero for a string like this "Hello".
Why MYSQL return zero ? "Hello" is a True Boolean Value.

```
SELECT 'Hello' IS FALSE; -> 1
```

Comment: Your question appears to be "why does MySQL behave differently to PHP?".. I'd like to know what makes you think they should behave the same?

Comment: Study [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html). Try to understand what datatype the operands are converted to before the comparing.

Answer (score 4):

PHP and MySQL are different systems, each with their own rules for how things are done. It's not surprising that they differ in edge cases (or even non-edge cases) like comparing a string to a boolean.

Booleans on MySQL are actually numbers, the `TRUE` literal is just an alias for the literal `1` and `FALSE` is just an alias for the literal `0` ([details here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/boolean-literals.html)). Because `'Hello'` is not a number, MySQL tries to convert it to a number ([Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina) said in a comment that, specifically, it converts to `DOUBLE`) to compare it with `FALSE` (which is `0`). But `'Hello'` doesn't define a number, so it gets converted to `0` (try `SELECT CAST('Hello' AS DOUBLE);` to see that happen). So you end up with `SELECT 0 IS 0`, which is `1` (aka `TRUE`).

Comment: *so it gets converted to 0 (try `SELECT CAST('Hello' AS DECIMAL);`* - incorrect. Both operands are converted to floating-point (DOUBLE).

Comment: @Akina - Thanks,, `DECIMAL` was just an example. I'll change it to `DOUBLE`.

Comment: MySQL's datatype used is DOUBLE. But in the [RM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) (by unknown reason) we see *... floating-point (**real**) numbers ...*. From the other side [RM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) tells that it is allowed to use non-standard REAL instead of DOUBLE...